# Java_Where is non_static methods are actually stored?

Tags: java, memory-management

Since in C++ all the methods (non-static and static) are global (stored in static memory area), I am wondering if it is also true for Java.

My guess is that the way Java stores object methods should be the same as in C++, since you can not have non-static methods stored in dynamic or stack, which will be memory-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a class, a JVM-internal representation of the class is created.  This contains, or has pointers to, all the data in the .class file, including the bytecode sequences for the individual methods.

As a part of the class loading process, a table of instance method pointers is created, with one "slot" for each method in either that class or (recursively) it's superclass.  The pointers to the individual bytecode sequences (and, should the code be JITCed, the machine code) are placed in that table.

There is only one instance of this table (and the data it points to) for all the instances of the associated class.

Answer (score 2):

All code is stored 'globally'. It has nothing to do with the heap or the stack. They are for *data*.